# How to write a multi-dimensional array of structs to disk using MPI I/O?

Tags: c++, mpi, mpi-io

I am trying to write an array of complex numbers to disk using MPI I/O. In particular, I am trying to achieve this using the function `MPI_File_set_view` so that I can generalise my code for higher dimensions. Please see my attempt below.

```
struct complex
{
    float real=0;
    float imag=0;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* Initialise MPI parallel branch */
    int id, nprocs;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &id);
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &nprocs);

    /* Create a datatype to represent structs of complex numbers */
    MPI_Datatype MPI_Complex;
    const int    lengths[2] = { 1, 1 };
    MPI_Datatype types[2] = { MPI_FLOAT, MPI_FLOAT };
    MPI_Aint     displacements[2], base_address;
    complex      dummy_complex;
    MPI_Get_address(&dummy_complex, &base_address);
    MPI_Get_address(&dummy_complex.real, &displacements[0]);
    MPI_Get_address(&dummy_complex.imag, &displacements[1]);
    displacements[0] = MPI_Aint_diff(displacements[0], base_address);
    displacements[1] = MPI_Aint_diff(displacements[1], base_address);
    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, lengths, displacements, types, &MPI_Complex);
    MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_Complex);

    /* Create a datatype to represent local arrays as subarrays of a global array */
    MPI_Datatype MPI_Complex_array;
    const int global_size[1] = { 100 };
    const int local_size[1] = { (id < nprocs-1 ? 100/nprocs : 100/nprocs + 100%nprocs) };
    const int glo_coord_start[1] = { id * (100/nprocs) };
    MPI_Type_create_subarray(1, global_size, local_size, glo_coord_start, MPI_ORDER_C,
                             MPI_Complex, &MPI_Complex_array);
    MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_Complex_array);

    /* Define and populate an array of complex numbers */
    complex *z = (complex*) malloc( sizeof(complex) * local_size[0] );
    /* ...other stuff here... */

    /* Write local data out to disk concurrently */
    MPI_Offset offset = 0;
    MPI_File file;
    MPI_File_open(comm, "complex_nums.dat", MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_WRONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);
    MPI_File_set_view(file, offset, MPI_Complex, MPI_Complex_array, "external", MPI_INFO_NULL);
    MPI_File_write_all(file, z, local_size[0], MPI_Complex, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_File_close(&file);

    /* ...more stuff here... */
}
```

However, with the above code, only the local data from the process labelled `id = 0` is being saved to disk. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? Thank you.

**N.B.** Please note that for this one dimensional example, I can avoid the problem by giving up on `MPI_File_set_view` and using something simpler like `MPI_File_write_at_all`. Nevertheless, I have not solved the underlying problem because I still don't understand why the above code does not work, and I would like a solution that can be generalised for multi-dimensional arrays. Your help is much appreciated in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: You're making things much too hard. 1. Since your struct is only two floats, you don't need a struct type: you can write your structs as an array of floats. 2. Using a one-dimensional subarray type is also overkill. I would compute an offset and `MPI_File_write_at`.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I will address your second point first. I agree. Using the subarray type for one dimension is an overkill. But I am trying to learn how it works so that I can write 3D arrays of complex numbers to disk. As for your first point, I am not sure I follow what you mean. Did you mean I should just use two arrays of floats instead of the struct? Thank you.

Comment: I've never tried using a subarray type for that. Why don't you start with a simple case of elementary types. There may be a problem with type extents so you may need to resize the type. Second point: an array of N complex numbers is the same as a single array of 2N floats.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I am quite fine with how smooth it works with elementary types. The problem is that I am trying to fit this piece of code in a larger project where I might not have the flexibility to choose how I represent arrays of complex data. What's your advice here, given the constraint that I must deal with arrays of structs? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is **not** to abort when a MPI-IO subroutine fails.
So unless you change this default behavior, you should always test the error code returned by MPI-IO subroutines.

In your case, `MPI_File_set_view()` fails because `external` is not a valid data representation.
I guess this is a typo and you meant `external32`.

Comment: It does not fail with an error code. The code compiles and executes fine. It's just that the saved data is not the entire global array but only the local array from process 0. In other words, `MPI_File_set_view` is somehow doing the wrong job in assigning the correct offsets in different processes.

Comment: Are you saying `MPI_File_set_view()` returns `MPI_SUCCESS`?

Comment: I thought `MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL` was the default for all MPI routines?

Comment: That is definitely not the case for MPI-IO with Open MPI.

Comment: You are right. Only "native" data representation is currently supported. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Stay blessed! :)